# Check if user with a specific ID exists

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I know you can get server member using `let user = guild.members.cache.get('ID')` and then check if member exists using `if(!user) return`, but how can I get a user with specific ID and check if this user exist at all if my bot doesn't share any servers with them?

Comment: I don't believe it's possible. For security reasons clients only have access to users and guilds they're associated with

Comment: @Elitezen The main reason I asked it because I found one website where you can get info about certain user if you have their ID

Comment: @Elitezen it is actually possible, one of current answers is correct!

Comment: Interesting, I don't think many know about this

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This would be more suited as a comment to another answer but I can't yet add them so;

The second method in the answer I'm referencing is the best way, however is incorrect. `client.users.fetch()` does not return `undefined`. If no user exists, it errors, so instead you must do

```js
let user;
try {
    user = await client.users.fetch("id", { force: true, cache: true }); // force skips cache checking so they don't need to be cached by the bot, cache will cache the user
} catch(err) {
    user = undefined;
}

// or
client.users.fetch("id", { force: true, cache: true })
.then(user => {
    // do something
})
.catch(err => {
    // user doesn't exist or another error occurred 
})
```

Comment: `const` variables must be initialized on definition, and cannot be reassigned, additionally `user` will already be undefined if the promise rejects, no need to manually assign it

Comment: Somehow managed to use const over let yeah, fixed now, and yeah I know it's not necessary to set it to undefined when it's already nullish, I just did it since it's nicer to look at imo

Comment: Also just included necessary options since I just realised I completely forgot to write them in

Comment: I started to believe it's not possible but suddenly, your answer is correct! Thanks!